# Confused about Autofac Middleware module

Tags: c#, autofac

So I'm following an example of setting up LoggerMiddleware which is demonstrated [here](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) which I've adapted to just use .NET Core's ILogger. We already had a LoggerModule which work pre v6 so I copied the creation code into the LoggerMiddleware class to suit.

What I don't understand is how to register this. There's no default constructor on the Module so I can't use `builder.RegisterModule<MiddlewareModule>()`. I know I can pre-create the MiddlewareModule passing in an instance of the LoggerMiddleware then `builder.RegisterModule(moduleInstance)` but this MiddlewareModule is supposed to be used for all Middleware we create. This doco page doesn't elaborate on that final detail. Do I just do this per instance of IResolveMiddleware?:

```
var loggerMiddlewareModule = new MiddlewareModule(new LoggerMiddleware());
builder.RegisterModule(loggerMiddlewareModule);

var otherMiddlewareModule = new MiddlewareModule(new OtherMiddleware());
builder.RegisterModule(otherMiddlewareModule);
```

My Middleware and Module:

```
public class LoggerMiddleware : IResolveMiddleware
{
    public PipelinePhase Phase => PipelinePhase.ParameterSelection;

    public void Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action<ResolveRequestContext> next)
    {
        var t = context.Registration.Activator.LimitType;

        // Add our parameters.
        context.ChangeParameters(context.Parameters.Union(
            new[]
            {
                new ResolvedParameter((p, i) => p.ParameterType == typeof(ILogger), (p, i) => GetLogger(i, t)),
                new ResolvedParameter(
                    (p, i) => p.ParameterType.GenericTypeArguments.Any() &&
                              p.ParameterType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ILogger<>),
                    (p, i) => GetGenericTypeLogger(i, t))
            }));

        // Continue the resolve.
        next(context);

        // Has an instance been activated?
        if (context.NewInstanceActivated)
        {
            var instanceType = context.Instance.GetType();

            // Get all the injectable properties to set.
            // If you wanted to ensure the properties were only UNSET properties,
            // here's where you'd do it.
            var properties = instanceType
                .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(ILogger) && p.CanWrite && p.GetIndexParameters().Length == 0);

            // Set the properties located.
            foreach (var propToSet in properties)
            {
                propToSet.SetValue(context.Instance, GetLogger(context, instanceType), null);
            }
        }
    }



    /// <summary>
    ///     The log cache.
    /// </summary>
    private static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object> _logCache = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, object>();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the logger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The component context.</param>
    /// <param name="declaringType">The type of logger.</param>
    /// <returns>The logger instance.</returns>
    private static object GetGenericTypeLogger(IComponentContext context, Type declaringType)
    {
        return _logCache.GetOrAdd(
            declaringType,
            x =>
            {
                var wrapper = typeof(LoggerWrapper<>);
                var specificWrapper = wrapper.MakeGenericType(declaringType);
                var instance = (ILoggerWrapper)Activator.CreateInstance(specificWrapper);

                var factory = context.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();

                return instance!.Create(factory);
            });
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Gets the logger.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The component context.</param>
    /// <param name="declaringType">The type of logger.</param>
    /// <returns>The logger instance.</returns>
    private static object GetLogger(IComponentContext context, Type declaringType)
    {
        return _logCache.GetOrAdd(
            declaringType,
            x =>
            {
                var factory = context.Resolve<ILoggerFactory>();

                return factory.CreateLogger(declaringType);
            });
    }


    /// <summary>
    ///     The <see cref="ILoggerWrapper" />
    ///     interface defines the method for creating a generic type logger.
    /// </summary>
    private interface ILoggerWrapper
    {
        /// <summary>
        ///     Creates a generic type logger using the specified factory.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="factory">The factory.</param>
        /// <returns>The logger.</returns>
        object Create(ILoggerFactory factory);
    }

    private class LoggerWrapper<T> : ILoggerWrapper
    {
        public object Create(ILoggerFactory factory)
        {
            return factory.CreateLogger<T>();
        }
    }

}

public class MiddlewareModule : Module
{
    private readonly IResolveMiddleware _middleware;

    public MiddlewareModule(IResolveMiddleware middleware)
    {
        _middleware = middleware;

    }

    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(IComponentRegistryBuilder componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        // Attach to the registrations pipeline build
        registration.PipelineBuilding += (sender, pipeline) =>
        {
            // Add our middleware to the pipeline
            pipeline.Use(_middleware);

        };
    }
```

===============

Further question:

So when I run this I'm getting DependencyResolutionException and not quite sure where to look.

[image]

This is what the middleware module registration looks like:
[image]

There are other standard modules doing RegisterType and Register calls.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right; that example `MiddlewareModule` registers a single instance of an `IResolveMiddleware` in the pipeline of every registration, so you need one instance of the module for each different middleware you want to add.

You could equally have a custom Module that registers multiple middleware, or construct a different middleware instance per-registration; this was just an example.

Comment: Thanks @alistair-evans I've added to my original post. DO you have any idea what might be leading to the dep resolution exception I'm getting?

Comment: Doesn't look like an Autofac error; we're just wrapping an exception thrown by a component ctor. Check the inner exception to see whats actually wrong.

Comment: I'm having a hard time knowing what to do with this one. I'm not directly handling the CompiledPageRouteModelProvider, not even really sure where to turn now. Has anyone already made an Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger middlware that would cover our scenario? Our current module resolver ILogger<> but also ILogger for non typed.

Comment: What I have done that gets me pas my broken scenario is to remove the ResolvedParameter for generic ILogger and my Blazor site now works. As I understand it ASP.NET Controllers require generic ILogger over ILogger so I'm not sure if this is going to completely fall over in a Core API / MVC site. Given this middleware intercepts and provides a plain ILogger have will the remaining pipeline manage to cater for ILogger<T> ?

Comment: You probably don't need to intercept the generic variant; the generic variant is already going to associate the logger with the type specified as a type parameter to the ILogger interface.

Comment: There has traditionally been an issue though with ASP.NET Controllers as they apparently can't be resolved with a non generic ILogger. In our case it's fine as non generic as we're in a Blazor application using Razor Pages, but if we move other ASP.NET MVC / API projects to use the ILoggerMiddleware the we'll have a problem.